# how to connect mysql and django in vscode virtual environment

Tags: python, django, libmysqlclient

If l try to run pip install mysqlclient in virtual environment l get this

pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [41 lines of output]
# Options for building extention module:
library_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\lib\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\lib']
libraries: ['kernel32', 'advapi32', 'wsock32', 'shlwapi', 'Ws2_32', 'crypt32', 'secur32', 'bcrypt', 'mariadbclient']
extra_link_args: ['/MANIFEST']
include_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\include']
extra_objects: []
define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)), ('**version**', '2.2.0')]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
running egg_info
writing src\mysqlclient.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying src\MySQLdb_mysql.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

```
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I used the same command in pycharm and it worked, but in vscode it doesnt, and  l want to use vscode for my django project